# CountDownLatch.await/countDown vs Thread.join/interrupt to wait for a single Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

To implement invokeLater and invokeAndWait like java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater/invokeAndWait, I need to call invokeLater and wait for the runnable in invokeAndWait.

Both CountDownLatch.await/countDown and Thread.join/interrupt seem to work, but which is better? Is there more simple way?

Thread.join/interrupt codes:

```
public interface EventQueue {
    /**
     * Executes a command in main thread.<p>
     * <b>Can be called outside main thread.</b>
     */
    public void invokeLater(Runnable runnable);

    /**
     * Executes and waits for a command in main thread.<p>
     * <b>MUST be called outside main thread.</b>
     */
    public default void invokeAndWait(Runnable runnable) {
        Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
        invokeLater(() -> {
            runnable.run();
            thread.interrupt();
        });
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

CountDownLatch.await/countDown codes:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public interface EventQueue {
    /**
     * Executes a command in main thread.<p>
     * <b>Can be called outside main thread.</b>
     */
    public void invokeLater(Runnable runnable);

    /**
     * Executes and waits for a command in main thread.<p>
     * <b>MUST be called outside main thread.</b>
     */
    public default void invokeAndWait(Runnable runnable) {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        invokeLater(() -> {
            runnable.run();
            latch.countDown();
        });
        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 for CountDownLatch.
It's simple and light-weighted than Thread.